# Parsing mathematical expression string

Tags: c, string

So this is my issue, I have to create a program that implements the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) in C. For this I first need to parse the given mathematical expression into it's component parts. So I figured a simple for loop over a given string would do the trick.

```
char *math_exp = "2 + 4";
for (int i = 0; (unsigned) i < strlen(math_expr); i++) {
    printf("%c", math_expr[i]);
}

> 2 + 4
```

But this quickly runs into an issue when a string contains a number with more digits than 1.

```
for (int i = 0; (unsigned) i < strlen(math_expr); i++) {
    // skip if char is a space
    if ((int) math_expr[i] == 32) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("%c ", math_expr[i]);
}
> 2 2 + 4
```

The 22 is now treated as two separate numbers. So I tried to loop over all tokens in the string by splitting the string using the delimiter SPACE.

```
char math_expr[] = "22 + 4";
char *token = strtok(math_expr, " ");

while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s ", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
> 22 + 4
```

This seemed to work but quickly ran into the issue of what to do when there's a bracket in the expression. e.g.:

```
char math_expr[] = "(22 + 2)";
char *token = strtok(math_expr, " ");

while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
> (22
> +
> 2)
```

And now I'm stuck, is there a way to circumvent this issue? I need to be able to extract every operator and number (with all possible digits) furthermore I also need to be able to distinguish brackets from numbers they are attached to. I hoped there was some easy way to do this. Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: `strtok(.... "() ")` ? or better `strpbrk(...., "() ")`. You need to write a parser, there is no easy way. Read one character at time and write a fully capable parser.

Comment: You have those parentheses because of operation priority? If not so you can eliminate parentheses. Also be aware, strtok affects the original string.

Comment: @sushibossftw yes they are there for operator precedence.

Comment: @PEREZje If this is more than an exercise, you should really do yourself a favor and use a lexer like (f)lex, maybe accompanied by a parser generator such as yacc/bison for such tasks.

Comment: There is a good introdution to implementing lexer and parser here: [LLVM tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl01.html) It's written in `c++`, but lexer part is written mostly in `c`. Maybe it worth attention.

Comment: the `(int)` cast is nonsense there. Also use `' '` instead of 32

Comment: @AnttiHaapala why is the int unnecessary? strcmp raised an error about pointers, what would be better? Furthermore I'll switch over to ' then, I come from Python3 and the distinction never really mattered. Is there a reason to use ' > "?

Comment: Of course there is. One is string, other is int. These have no relation to Python

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the distinction between ' and "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) is the first step towards syntactic analysis. As such, it is probably a good idea to encapsulate it into a layer of abstraction, a function that yields one token at a time. This function also discards white space and combines consecutive digits into numbers. It is hard to delegate these steps to `strtok()`. Finally, the function may rewrap single characters into more structured information.

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define T_NUMBER 0
#define T_OPERATOR 1
#define T_BRACKET 2

typedef struct {
  int type;
  int value;
} token;

/* Reads the next token from stdin. Returns 1 on success, 0 on EOL. */
int next_token(token *t) {
  char c;

  /* discard spaces silently */
  do {
    c = getchar();
  } while (c == ' ');

  if (isdigit(c)) {
    t->type = T_NUMBER;
    t->value = 0;
    do {
      t->value = t->value * 10 + (c - '0');
      c = getchar();
    } while (isdigit(c));
    ungetc(c, stdin); /* save the non-digit for next time */

  } else if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/') {
    t->type = T_OPERATOR;
    t->value = c;

  } else if (c == '(' || c == ')') {
    t->type = T_BRACKET;
    t->value = c;

  } else if (c == '\n') {
    ungetc(c, stdin); /* make sure we always return 0 from now on */
    return 0;

  } else {
    /* handle illegal character */

  }

  return 1;
}

int main() {

  token t;

  while (next_token(&t)) {
    switch (t.type) {
      case T_NUMBER:   printf("number   %d\n", t.value); break;
      case T_OPERATOR: printf("operator %c\n", t.value); break;
      case T_BRACKET:  printf("bracket  %c\n", t.value); break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
(22+   37 * ( 1534-9)) + 18
bracket  (
number   22
operator +
number   37
operator *
bracket  (
number   1534
operator -
number   9
bracket  )
bracket  )
operator +
number   18
```